# show another form

Tags: c#, winapi

I want to show windows of another application if it is hidden. More specifically, I want to show the main window of already launched application if the user tries to launch it again. I've already implemented monitoring of duplicate application launches. Tried to do as in [here](http://codebetter.com/paullaudeman/2004/07/17/windows-forms-tip-ensure-only-one-instance-of-your-application-is-running-at-a-time/) but failed. Thinking of doing it using remoting, but I understand that this is not the best practice, although I won't need to bother with Windows API in that case.

Comment: So you actually want _your_ application to be single instance? If so, you should find many good examples of similar questions on StackOverflow already...

Comment: Already supported by .NET: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/7c6e0d56-d942-46f5-b27a-d627e60eebbe/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already implemented it using remoting, but I'll consider other ways of doing this when I have more free time. Here's how I did it:
In the form class we have:

```
        public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        this.ShowFromFormShower = new FormShower.ShowFromFormShowerDelegate(this.ShowFromFormShower1);
        FormShower.Register(this);
    }

    private void ShowFromFormShower1()
    {            
        this.Show();
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        this.BringToFront();            
    }
    public PKW.FormShower.ShowFromFormShowerDelegate ShowFromFormShower;
```

Also a remoting class needs to be created:

```
    public class FormShower : MarshalByRefObject
{     
    /// <summary>
    /// For remote calls.
    /// </summary>
    public void Show()
    {
        if (FormShower.m == null)
            throw new ApplicationException("Could not use remoting to show Main form because the reference is not set in the FormShower class.");
        else
            FormShower.m.Invoke(FormShower.m.ShowFromFormShower);
    }
    private const int PortNumber = 12312;
    private static Main m = null;
    public delegate void ShowFromFormShowerDelegate();
    internal static void Register(Main m)
    {
        if (m == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("m");
        FormShower.m = m;
        ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(new TcpChannel(FormShower.PortNumber), false);            
        RemotingConfiguration.RegisterActivatedServiceType(typeof(FormShower));
    }
    internal static void CallShow()
    {
        TcpClientChannel c = new TcpClientChannel();
        ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(c, false);
        RemotingConfiguration.RegisterActivatedClientType(typeof(FormShower), "tcp://localhost:"+PortNumber.ToString());
        FormShower fs = new FormShower();
        fs.Show();
    }
}
```

So if the user tries to launch the application a second time the application launches FormShower.CallShow method.

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty hackish way of doing things. I'd advise using named pipes (`System.IO.Pipes`) to signal the first copy of your app. The first copy, upon receiving the signal, will activate the window itself. And no worries about any permissions either.

Answer (score 0):

Another pretty easy way to do it is using a Windows Event, represented in .NET as the `System.Threading.EventWaitHandle` class.

Create a thread in the application, that all it does is wait on a named event. When the event is signalled, this thread will use `Form.BeginInvoke` to make the main window appear, and go back to wait on the event.

From the new instance of the application, you will only have to signal the event.

This requires a little less work than using pipes.

Note that either way (using pipes, windows, or events), you always have to deal with permissions.

For example, if UAC is enabled, and the existing application instance is running as admin, the new instance may not be able to send it the message to show the window, unless you made sure to set the proper permissions (e.g. on the pipe or the event, whatever your method is) in advance.